# Unescaped java not matching in regex matcher.find()

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code that basically matches "Match this:" and keeps the first sentence.  However, there are sometimes unicode characters that get passed into the text that are causing backtracking on other more complicated regex's. Escaping seem to alleviate the backtracking index out of range exceptions.  However, now the regex isn't matching.

What i would like to know is why this regex isn't matching when escaped?  If you comment out the escape/unescape java lines everything.

```
    String text = "Keep this\n\n"
            + "Match this:\n\nDelete  this";
    text = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text);
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^Match this:$",
            Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        text = text.substring(0, m.start()).replaceAll("[\\n]+$", "");
    }
    text = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Without `StringEscapeUtils` I get output as: `Keep this`

Comment: Gut reaction is that there's some other kind of character at the start or end of the line ... Javadoc says, "By default, the regular expressions ^ and $ ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence. If MULTILINE mode is activated then ^ matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator except at the end of input. When in MULTILINE mode $ matches just before a line terminator or the end of the input sequence. " So maybe some other line terminator sneaks in there when string is escaped.

Comment: What if you use \Q and \E as specified in the Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ?

Comment: @ScottShipp: you are definitely on point with that summary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i would like to know is why this regex isn't matching when escaped?

When you escape string like `"foo\nbar"` which printed is similar to

```
foo
bar
```

you are getting `"foo\\nbar"` which printed looks like

```
foo\nbar
```

It happens because `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` escapes also `\n` and is replacing it with `\\n`, so it is no longer line separator but simple literal, so it can't be matched with `^` or `$`.

Possible solution could be replacing back `"\\n"` with `"\n"` after `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`. You will need to be careful here, not to "unescapee" real `"\\n"` which after replacing would give you `"\\\\n"` which printed would look like `\\n`. So maybe use

```
text = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text);
text = text.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\n", "\n");// escape `\n` 
                                               // if it is not preceded with `\`
//do your job

//and now you can unescape your text (\n will stay \n)
text = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text);
```

---

Another option could be creating your own implementation similar to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`. If you take a look at this method body you will see

```
return ESCAPE_JAVA.translate(input);
```

Where `ESCAPE_JAVA` is

```
CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_JAVA = 
  new LookupTranslator(
    new String[][] { 
      {"\"", "\\\""},
      {"\\", "\\\\"},
  }).with(
    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE())
  ).with(
    UnicodeEscaper.outsideOf(32, 0x7f) 
);
```

and `EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE()` returns clone of

```
String[][] JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE = {
    {"\b", "\\b"},
    {"\n", "\\n"},
    {"\t", "\\t"},
    {"\f", "\\f"},
    {"\r", "\\r"}
};
```

array. So if you provide here your own table which will tell explicitly that `\n` should be left as it is (so it should be replaced with itself `\n`) your code will ignore it.

So this is how your own implementation can look like

```
private static CharSequenceTranslator translatorIgnoringLineSeparators = 
    new LookupTranslator(
        new String[][] { 
                { "\"", "\\\"" }, 
                { "\\", "\\\\" }, 
        }).with(
                new LookupTranslator(new String[][] {
                        { "\b", "\\b" },
                        { "\n", "\n"  },//this will handle `\n` and will not change it
                        { "\r", "\r"  },//this will handle `\r` and will not change it
                        { "\t", "\\t" }, 
                        { "\f", "\\f" },
        })).with(UnicodeEscaper.outsideOf(32, 0x7f));

public static String myJavaEscaper(CharSequence input) {
    return translatorIgnoringLineSeparators.translate(input);
}
```

This method will prevent escaping `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: thx for the detailed response. i'll give that shot, however, do you know if it's possible to escape only those funky surrogate Unicode characters?

Comment: @JaJ Do you know range of these unicode characters you want to escape? If you do then you can try with something like `UnicodeEscaper`. Here is example of how to escape characters between `a` and `z` : `UnicodeEscaper.between('a', 'c').translate("abcdef")`. This will generate `\u0061\u0062\u0063def`. If you want to get back original message then just use `new UnicodeUnescaper().translate(escapedText)`.

Comment: thx. that is definitely another route that I can take instead of completely esc everything.  (y)

Comment: I posted variant of method similar to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` which will not escape `\n` or `\r`. Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: so when I get this translated it goes to  \u1F4F1. So, how can I get that back to it's original format (the emoticon) after i run my regex?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was focused on problem with `\n` rather with ``. I assumed that you checked that `StringEscapeUtils` can successfully escape and unescape your special characters, otherwise why to even bother using this library. For now I don't know why `\u1F4F1` would be generated, since it is not valid Unicode syntax :/

Comment: correct, it's outside the BMP.  your function works great. i just noticed that phone icon char was bing converted back if I unescaped using UnicodeEscaper or stringEscapeUtils.